# Why isn't my perl one liner working?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to grab the number of errors from a HTML log file. Here's my code (yes, I know I'm mixing bash and perl):

```
 for line in `cat paths.txt`; do   grep Failed ${line} | perl -pe 'm/\d+/'; done
```

I'm expecting to simply get a list of numbers, e.g.,

```
0 
1 
0 
0 
0 
1 
6
```

But instead I'm getting the entire line that contains the error, e.g.,

> ```
>       Total Failed: <strong>0</strong>
>       Total Failed: <strong>1</strong>
>       Total Failed: <strong>0</strong>
>       Total Failed: <strong>0</strong>
>       Total Failed: <strong>0</strong>
>       Total Failed: <strong>1</strong>
>       Total Failed: <strong>6</strong>
> ```

What am I over looking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`perl -pe 'm/\d+/';` Will simply perform a pattern match, the line printed will not be changed. If you want to only print the number, you need something like:

```
perl -pe 's/\D+//g'          # change $_
```

or

```
perl -nE 'say $1 if /(\d+)/' # only print the match
```

But why not use all perl?

```
perl -nwE 'say $1 if /Failed.*(\d+)/' paths.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it's been a long day and obvious answers were eluding me.  Time for bed.

Comment: BTW, I wasn't familiar with "say" before, nifty.  Thanks again.

Comment: @phi - it's a new feature in Perl 5.10+ . http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html

Comment: Hmmm, the last example isn't working (I assume you meant a lower case 'e').

Comment: No, `-E` means `like -e, but enables all optional features`. It is required to enable `say`. And FYI, "isn't working" is a sadly inadequate description of a problem, and not suited for anything except frustrating the good people of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead:

```
perl -ne '/\d+/ && print "$&\n"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply this?

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+' paths.txt
```

Comment: Well, you need to do it only for the lines that match 'Failed'.